# Incorrect spacing? I fail to see where

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've written a function that allows me to read some elements of a table for the rest of my program, however, when I run it python IDLE says *'Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation'* on the line `elif currentState == True:`. Where am I tabbing incorrectly here?

```
def irOn(irRecv, irData):
    if irRecv == True:
        appLabel, irFrq, currentState = irTable[irData]
        if currentState == False:
                        global newState
                        newState = True
                elif currentState == True:
                        newState = False

        print("New ", appLabel, " status ", newState, " via ", irFrq)
        global recvData
        recvData = False
```

Comment: Your elif is in incorrect place...

Comment: Along with the misaligned `elif`, the result for your `if` condition is tabbed incorrectly as well.

Comment: If and elif must be at same indentation. Isn't that obvious?..

Comment: My applogies... it is in the IDLE... http://i.imgur.com/XNfzeOT.png

Comment: Why do you have like 30 spaces suddenly?... All lines should be indented NOT MORE that 4 spaces more than previous. Please read Python PEP8.

Comment: However, removing and replacing the tabbing seems to have worked... Odd.

Comment: On that image the indentations under if and elif are far off, 4 spaces or a tab, OK?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it looks aligned. It may be wrong if you are mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: But im really not, im using the tabbing system in the IDLE, i never make the spacing with spaces, I always use the tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Error message I assume you are using PyCharm IDE or any similair.
To avoid problems like that use the auto intendation option and reformat your code if you can't find the mistake: Select Code, click `code` in menu and `Reformat code...`

```
def irOn(irRecv, irData):
    if irRecv == True:
        appLabel, irFrq, currentState = irTable[irData]
        if currentState == False:
            global newState
            newState = True
        elif currentState == True:
           newState = False

        print("New ", appLabel, " status ", newState, " via ", irFrq)
        global recvData
        recvData = False
```

Comment: Yea I was using the default python IDLE so not sure how i managed to ness up the spacing but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def irOn(irRecv, irData):
    if irRecv == True:
        appLabel, irFrq, currentState = irTable[irData]
        if currentState == False:
            global newState
            newState = True
        elif currentState == True:
            newState = False

        print("New ", appLabel, " status ", newState, " via ", irFrq)
        global recvData
        recvData = False
```

`elif` is in an incorrect place, it should be the same indentation as `if`.

Indentation in python doesn't have to be aligned by tabs, but by relative position to one another. To clear up more confusion, http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk

Comment: Ok given that ago and now it says 'Expected an indented block' on `if irRecv == True:`

Comment: I fail to see why this is down voted, after the edits.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of elif needs to be matched with that of if.